# ListView: How do sort my list or arrayList by a specific element?

Tags: android, listview

1. For instance show only automobile that are; “Mercedes” or
   ‘’Nissan?”
2. Or by YearOfManufacture; only automobile
   manufactured in 2004 in my listView?

My Automobil class looks like this

```
public class AutoMobil {
     private String make;
     private String brandName;
     private int yearOfManufacture;
  }
```

My autoMobil populated list looks like this;

```
private void autoMobileList() {
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Corolla’’, ‘’2011’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Corolla’’, ‘’2002’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Mark2’’, ‘’1998’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Camry’’, ‘’2004’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Corona’’, ‘’2011’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Nissan’’, ‘’March’’, ‘’2013’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Nissan’’, ‘’Micra’’, ‘’2001’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Nissan’’, ‘’Laurel’’, ‘’2014’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Mercedes’’, ‘’SL500’’, ‘’2004’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Mercedes’’, ‘’190E’’, ‘’1992’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Mercedes’’, ‘’C200’’, ‘’1993’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Hiace’’, ‘’1998’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Hiace’’, ‘’2003’’));
    MyAutoMobilList.add(new AutoMobil(“Toyota’’, ‘’Vitz’’, ‘’2004’’));

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android-java- How to sort a list of objects by a certain value within the object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109890/android-java-how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-a-certain-value-within-the-object)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540605/searching-doesnt-work-in-arrayadapter-and-listview/29543018#29543018). I have answered it before. Your requirement is similar to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by Brand Name (`String`):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<AutoMobil>() {
        public int compare(AutoMobil v1, AutoMobil v2) {
        return v1.getBrandName().compareTo(v2.getBrandName());
    }
});
```

Sort by Year Of Manufacture (`int`):

```
Collections.sort(conversations, new Comparator<AutoMobil>(){
                public int compare(AutoMobil s1, AutoMobil s2) {
        if (s1.getYearOfManufacture() < s2.getYearOfManufacture())
            return 1;
        if (s1.getYearOfManufacture() > s2.getYearOfManufacture())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
});
```

Show only specific items:

```
ArrayList<AutoMobil> list_to_show = new ArrayList<AutoMobil>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
     if (list.getBrandName().equals("Nissan"))
        list_to_show.add(list.get(i));
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch it works perfect in java. But I still have problems or errors when placing the collections.sort instances in my android activity. Should codes be applied to my adapter? if so, How should I do it?

Comment: @Kim make sure you have this import java.util.Collections;