# Sort a item inside an object and load in a listview

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview

I'm trying to load set of data to a list in ascending order. I have `DistanceObject` object and its as shown below,

```
            DistanceObject mObject = new DistanceObject();

            mObject.setOutletname(object.getString("LocationName"));
            mObject.setAddress(object.getString("LocationAddress"));
            mObject.setDistance(strdistance);
            mListObjects.add(mObject);
```

**Loading data to listview**

I can use below shown code and load the data to listview without sorting the list,

```
adapter = new CustomListOutlets(ActivityListOutlets.this,
                    mListObjects);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My problem is I want to sort the `strdistance` and load the data to a `ListView`. I can sort the `strdistance` using `Collections.sort()` but with the sorting of `strdistance` I want to sort its `LocationName` and `LocationAddress`.

Any help will be appreciated to achieve this task, Thanks in advance.

**Updated**

```
final List<DistanceObject> mListObjects = new ArrayList<DistanceObject>();
DistanceObject mObject = new DistanceObject();

                mObject.setOutletname(object.getString("LocationName"));
                mObject.setAddress(object.getString("LocationAddress"));
                mObject.setDistance(strdistance);

                Collections.sort(mListObjects, new Comparator<DistanceObject>() {
                    public int compare(DistanceObject s1, DistanceObject s2) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(s1.getDistance()) < Integer.parseInt(s2.getDistance()))
                            return 1;
                        if (Integer.parseInt(s1.getDistance()) > Integer.parseInt(s2.getDistance()))
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    }
                });

            }

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_outlets);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            adapter = new CustomListOutlets(ActivityListOutlets.this,
                    mListObjects);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort some `List` you can use `Collections.sort()`.
Use [my example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562060/listview-how-do-sort-my-list-or-arraylist-by-a-specific-element/29562243#29562243).

Comment: Check my updated question please. When I run this it gives me empty list view

Comment: @modabeckham I see you create 1 object ('DistanceObject mObject'), but i do not see where you create 'mListObjects' and how do you set this List.